# How to save data to a database from file_get_html($url)?

Tags: php, arrays, object, dom, web-scraping

I can't save data to database from file_get_html($url) function. My script is showing data nicely by scraping from a url. But I can't save the showed data to a database. It shows error between object and array. I can't even show data by array index. Such as $value[0]. Here is my code sample:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crawler");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://www.realestate.com.au/sold/in-perth/list-1";

//Address Collection
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find("h2") as $key => $value){
echo $value."<br>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO data (info) VALUES ('$value')");
if (!$result){
    echo "Error!<br>";
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crawler");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://www.realestate.com.au/sold/in-perth/list-1";

//Address Collection
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find("h2") as $key => $value){
echo $value."<br>";
}
$value = base64_encode($value);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO data (info) VALUES ('$value')");
if (!$result){
    echo "Error!<br>";

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Its saving to database now. But I can't read the saved data. It looks:PGgyPjxhIGhyZWY9Jy9wcm9wZXJ0eS1hcGFydG1lbnQtd2EtcGVydGgtMTE1NTg2MTk1JyBjbGFzcz0nbmFtZScgcmVsPSdsaXN0aW5nTmFtZSc+OTA2IC8gIDMwNSBNdXJyYXkgU3RyZWV0LCBQZXJ0aCwgV0EgNjAwMDwvYT48L2gyPg==

Comment: Simply use base64_encode while  retrieving  data from database. Suppose you are getting this data from database and save it into $data
now use some thing like this : 


     echo base64_encode($data);

Comment: Yes, its saving to database now and I can read it by decode. Is there any way to save the data without encode? Thanks @daniyalahmad

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer please accept it. So it will help for future readers.
It's the best way to store html tags to database (secure). Other options are there but it could be much complicated.

Answer (score 0):

$value need convert to a string before write to DB. You can show array or object use

`echo '<pre>';
print_r($value);
echo '</pre>';`

or

`var_dump($value)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code is showing the whole object with arrays. But my problem is, I can't save the value of $value to the "info' field of "data" table. How can?